# Do I need to check if the data exists through SELECT before INSERT?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, uuid

I am currently using Java with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA to connect to a database.
In my table, there is a `UUID` column with a Unique Key constraint.

My question is, do I need to perform a SELECT before an INSERT to check for any duplicates to avoid an Exception upon insertion? However, in most cases, the SELECT will not return any duplicate data, which makes me feel like it's a wasted query.

Should I nevertheless perform a SELECT before every INSERT to ensure that data is not duplicated, even for the rare cases where it might happen?

Comment: *in most cases, the SELECT will not return any duplicate data,* then catch the Exception?

Comment: The answer depends on your use case. However, why you then need a unique key for a record if duplication is acceptable? Think about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No, if the database has a unique primary key constraint, then attempting a duplicate insertion will raise an exception.

You will need to add code to handle the exception. Typically such code would calculate a new UUID then retry the insert.

Answer (score 0):

It is a more optimal solution to handle exceptions than to place an unnecessary query in the code. What also needs to be resolved is that the exceptions for duplication must be handled separately from other database exceptions. For example, check the Exception message in the catch case:

```
catch (Exception e) {
  if (e.getMessage().contains("Duplicate")) { ... }
  else { ... }
}
```

Or, as Ziv suggested in the comment, you can catch specified exceptions. In this case SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException will be thrown (or its subclass, but it depends of the driver vendor).

Comment: To use catch exceptions, it's better to categorize them for different types of errors rather than catching a general exception.

try{
   doSomething...
}catch(ConstraintExcpetion ex){
  doSomething...
}catch(Exception ex){
  doSomething...
}

Comment: @Ziv you are right, I edited the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `select` check with the `insert` to avoid an error by only inserting when there isn't already a row for the key:

```
insert into mytable
select
   id_value,
   col2_value,
   col3_value
from dual
where not exists (select * from mytable where id = id_value)
```

Code this as a `@NativeQuery`.

Some databases don't require `from dual` (eg postgres).